# Executing a simple SQL Server stored procedure from php

Tags: php, sql-server

First of all: I did a research on google and stackoverflow, but it does not helped me.

I'm a beginner, so please do not blame me directly by just reading the title and voting me down. Stackoverflow seems to be **very** aggressive sometimes :(

I'm trying to execute a simple stored procedure from PHP.
Connecting to the database works.

This code also works through a query in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
Execute SP_TPL_DeleteUser
@ExternalFieldID = 22
```

Regarding to this manuals: [PHP Stored Procedures and SQL Server](http://www.sweeting.org/mark/blog/2005/02/24/php-stored-procedures-and-sql-server) and [MSSQL Bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-bind.php)

I build this lines of code:

```
$id=22;
$stmt=mssql_init("SP_TPL_DeleteUser", $conn);
mssql_bind($stmt, "@ExternalFieldID", $ExternalFieldID, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 255);
mssql_execute($stmt);
mssql_free_statement($stmt);
```

My output is:

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_init() in
>   C:\Users\kians_000\dev\traka\index.php on line 32

Of course I tried playing around, but nothing works :(
I would be thankful for any tips.

Edit:

I can connect to the DB with this:

```
$serverName = "KIAN-PC";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"T32Database");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn )
{
    echo "Connection established.\n";
}
else
{
    echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

But a simple query like this:

```
$version = mssql_query('SELECT *  FROM [T32Database].[dbo].[TUsers]');
$row = mssql_fetch_array($version);

echo $row[0];
```

Produces this output:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_query() in C:\Users\kians_000\dev\traka\index.php on line 42

phpinfo show me this:

> sqlsrv
>
> sqlsrv support    enabled
>
> Directive Local Value Master Value 
>   sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize  10240   10240 sqlsrv.LogSeverity    0   0 
>   sqlsrv.LogSubsystems  0   0 sqlsrv.WarningsReturnAsErrors On  On

Edit 3:
I tried out all drivers. This is the only one that works.
Maybe something with my source is wrong.

```
<?php

//-----------------------------------------------
// Connect to SQL Server DB
//-----------------------------------------------

$serverName = "KIAN-PC";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"T32Database");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn )
{
    echo "Connection established.\n";
}
else
{
    echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//-----------------------------------------------
// Perform operations with connection.
//-----------------------------------------------

$version = mssql_query('SELECT *  FROM [T32Database].[dbo].[TUsers]');
$row = mssql_fetch_array($version);

echo $row[0];

/* Close the connection. */
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

My output is:

> Connection established.  ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   mssql_query() in C:\Users\kians_000\dev\traka\index.php on line 42

Comment: This looks like a PHP issue.  Perhaps the MSSQL library is not properly linked in?

Comment: It is linked in properly. I can connect to the db.

Comment: Undefined function means the code for `mssql_init` is not found.  I would not think it connects to your DB.

Comment: The output is:
Connection established. 
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_query() in C:\Users\kians_000\dev\traka\index.php on line 42

Answer (score 2):

Instead of binding try calling your procedure as a query:

```
mssql_query('exec SP_TPL_DeleteUser @ExternalFieldID = ' . $ExternalFieldID, $con);
```

Comment: I tried it this way:
$ExternalFieldID = 22;
mssql_query('exec SP_TPL_DeleteUser @ExternalFieldID = ' . $ExternalFieldID, $conn);
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_query() in C:\Users\kians_000\dev\traka\index.php on line 37

Comment: so what, from all functions only `mssql_connect` works? I can understand `mssql_init` missing if you are using freetds driver, but not the `mssql_query` :-/

Comment: I added the following line to my php.ini
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
maybe this is the wrong driver?

Comment: I tried out all drivers now. This one seems to be the only one which is working.

Comment: In edit 3 you will find the whole source now.
Maybe something is wrong with that?

Comment: I think I found something:
My first command is sqlsrv_connect my second is mssql_fetch_array
I think this are two different libs.
I found this libary manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php and at least I do not get an error.
Still trying it out.

Comment: I mixed together two different drivers.

There are mssql and sqlsrv drivers. Check if the statements begin with mssql_ or sqlsrv_ I use MSSQL Express 2012 and it seems like the mssql drivers aren't used anyway.
Thanks for everybodys help anyway!
In 4 hours I can reply my own question and post a hello world for everybody else after me, which works.

Comment: Good job narrowing it down to the specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

I mixed together two different drivers.

There are mssql and sqlsrv drivers.
Check if the statements begin with mssql_ or sqlsrv_
I use MSSQL Express 2012 and it seems like the mssql drivers aren't used anyway.

This here works now (as a hello world):

```
<?php

//-----------------------------------------------
// Connect to MSSQL-DB
//-----------------------------------------------

$serverName = "KIAN-PC";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"T32Database");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


if( $conn === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

//-----------------------------------------------
// Perform operations with connection.
//-----------------------------------------------

if( $client_info = sqlsrv_client_info( $conn)) {
    foreach( $client_info as $key => $value) {
        echo $key.": ".$value."<br />";
    }
} else {
    echo "Error in retrieving client info.<br />";
}

/* Close the connection. */
sqlsrv_close( $conn);

?>
```

Thanks for everybodys help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WAMP, make sure that the mssql module is enabled. It will have a checkmark next to its name in the context menu if it is.

Comment: Libary is linked in correctly and the mssql module is enabled.
I can connect to the db.